# Connect Superset to a database with JDBC Driver (.jar)

Tags: jdbc, apache-superset

Is there any way to connect to a database with a JDBC driver that does not have a python driver or SQLAlchemy dialect.

I have read the documentation and everywhere they mention the need for these two elements.
I tryed with SQLAlchemy-jdbc unsucessfully.

Thanks!